# How to install Ubuntu 20.04 on external SSD without changing 18.04 install on SSD inside

Tags: ubuntu, boot, external-hard-drive, grub

I tried installing Ubuntu 20.04 on an external disk (erasing the disk and install with LVM and full-disk encryption). This worked excellently; but after removing the external disk and rebooting, my old 18.04 install that is on the internal SSD failed to boot.

After some time in boot-rescue I finally got it to boot again; but I really want to try 20.04 on an external disk.

The problem seems to come from the 'install bootloader' part in the install; where I picked the external disk. It seems to remove the bootloader on the internal disk.

**Is this something that is expected? Or did I do something wrong?**

Btw. I have a Lenovo Thinkpad E580, which is a PITA to open, as can be seen in this screenshot from the [manual](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/tp_e580_e585_hmm_en.pdf), so I prefer a non-hardware based solution if possible :)

[image]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131204/install-ubuntu-to-an-external-usb-disk-and-switch-it-with-internal-disk-later/1131214#1131214 has a solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Disconnect the internal SSD or disable it in the BIOS.
2. Install 20.04 to the external drive.
3. Test booting into 20,04 on the external drive.
4. Reconnect/reenable the internal SSD.

Comment: I would really prefer not modifying my laptop internals. But yes, this would work I guess.

Comment: You must be a lucky older-Thinkpad owner. I switched from a E570 (easy) to a E580, which has 9 screws AND annoying plastic click-bits, which makes it a PITA to do anything hardware-related.

Comment: Most BIOSs let you disable drives without disconnecting them